# What is causing the Elasticsearch service to ignore my jvm.options?

Tags: centos, elasticsearch

In my `/etc/elasticsearch/jvm.options`

I have set my heap size with:

```
-Xms256m
-Xmx256m
```

However when I restart the service, memory keeps rising until it runs out and the service is stopped abruptly:

```
[root@st2 elasticsearch]# sudo systemctl status elasticsearch
● elasticsearch.service - Elasticsearch
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/elasticsearch.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: active (running) since Fri 2019-06-14 14:05:15 UTC; 7s ago
     Docs: http://www.elastic.co
 Main PID: 20280 (java)
    Tasks: 22
   Memory: 486.6M
   CGroup: /system.slice/elasticsearch.service
           ├─20280 /bin/java -Xms256m -Xmx256m -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:CMSInitiatingOccupan...
           └─20359 /usr/share/elasticsearch/modules/x-pack-ml/platform/linux-x86_64/bin/control..
```

I am on using `centos`:

```
[root@st2 elasticsearch]# cat /etc/centos-release
CentOS Linux release 7.6.1810 (Core)
```

More Info:

**Systemd service**

```
[root@st2 elasticsearch]# systemctl cat elasticsearch
# /usr/lib/systemd/system/elasticsearch.service
[Unit]
Description=Elasticsearch
Documentation=http://www.elastic.co
Wants=network-online.target
After=network-online.target

[Service]
RuntimeDirectory=elasticsearch
PrivateTmp=true
Environment=ES_HOME=/usr/share/elasticsearch
Environment=ES_PATH_CONF=/etc/elasticsearch
Environment=PID_DIR=/var/run/elasticsearch
Environment=ES_HEAP_SIZE=256M
EnvironmentFile=-/etc/sysconfig/elasticsearch

WorkingDirectory=/usr/share/elasticsearch

User=elasticsearch
Group=elasticsearch

ExecStart=/usr/share/elasticsearch/bin/elasticsearch -p ${PID_DIR}/elasticsearch.pid --quiet

# StandardOutput is configured to redirect to journalctl since
# some error messages may be logged in standard output before
# elasticsearch logging system is initialized. Elasticsearch
# stores its logs in /var/log/elasticsearch and does not use
# journalctl by default. If you also want to enable journalctl
# logging, you can simply remove the "quiet" option from ExecStart.
StandardOutput=journal
StandardError=inherit

# Specifies the maximum file descriptor number that can be opened by this process
LimitNOFILE=65535

# Specifies the maximum number of processes
LimitNPROC=4096

# Specifies the maximum size of virtual memory
LimitAS=infinity

# Specifies the maximum file size
LimitFSIZE=infinity

# Disable timeout logic and wait until process is stopped
TimeoutStopSec=0

# SIGTERM signal is used to stop the Java process
```

**/etc/elasticsearch/jvm.options**

```
## JVM configuration

################################################################
## IMPORTANT: JVM heap size
################################################################
##
## You should always set the min and max JVM heap
## size to the same value. For example, to set
## the heap to 4 GB, set:
##
## -Xms4g
## -Xmx4g
##
## See https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/heap-size.html
## for more information
##
################################################################

# Xms represents the initial size of total heap space
# Xmx represents the maximum size of total heap space

-Xms256m
-Xmx256m

################################################################
## Expert settings
################################################################
##
## All settings below this section are considered
## expert settings. Don't tamper with them unless
## you understand what you are doing
##
################################################################

## GC configuration
-XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC
-XX:CMSInitiatingOccupancyFraction=75
-XX:+UseCMSInitiatingOccupancyOnly

## G1GC Configuration
# NOTE: G1GC is only supported on JDK version 10 or later.
# To use G1GC uncomment the lines below.
# 10-:-XX:-UseConcMarkSweepGC
# 10-:-XX:-UseCMSInitiatingOccupancyOnly
# 10-:-XX:+UseG1GC
# 10-:-XX:InitiatingHeapOccupancyPercent=75

## DNS cache policy
# cache ttl in seconds for positive DNS lookups noting that this overrides the
# JDK security property networkaddress.cache.ttl; set to -1 to cache forever
-Des.networkaddress.cache.ttl=60
# cache ttl in seconds for negative DNS lookups noting that this overrides the
# JDK security property networkaddress.cache.negative ttl; set to -1 to cache
# forever
-Des.networkaddress.cache.negative.ttl=10

## optimizations

# pre-touch memory pages used by the JVM during initialization
-XX:+AlwaysPreTouch

## basic

# explicitly set the stack size
-Xss1m

# set to headless, just in case
-Djava.awt.headless=true

# ensure UTF-8 encoding by default (e.g. filenames)
-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8

# use our provided JNA always versus the system one
-Djna.nosys=true

# turn off a JDK optimization that throws away stack traces for common
# exceptions because stack traces are important for debugging
-XX:-OmitStackTraceInFastThrow

# flags to configure Netty
-Dio.netty.noUnsafe=true
-Dio.netty.noKeySetOptimization=true
-Dio.netty.recycler.maxCapacityPerThread=0

# log4j 2
-Dlog4j.shutdownHookEnabled=false
-Dlog4j2.disable.jmx=true

-Djava.io.tmpdir=${ES_TMPDIR}

## heap dumps

# generate a heap dump when an allocation from the Java heap fails
# heap dumps are created in the working directory of the JVM
-XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError

# specify an alternative path for heap dumps; ensure the directory exists and
# has sufficient space
-XX:HeapDumpPath=/var/lib/elasticsearch

# specify an alternative path for JVM fatal error logs
-XX:ErrorFile=/var/log/elasticsearch/hs_err_pid%p.log

## JDK 8 GC logging

8:-XX:+PrintGCDetails
8:-XX:+PrintGCDateStamps
8:-XX:+PrintTenuringDistribution
8:-XX:+PrintGCApplicationStoppedTime
8:-Xloggc:/var/log/elasticsearch/gc.log
8:-XX:+UseGCLogFileRotation
8:-XX:NumberOfGCLogFiles=32
8:-XX:GCLogFileSize=64m

# JDK 9+ GC logging
9-:-Xlog:gc*,gc+age=trace,safepoint:file=/var/log/elasticsearch/gc.log:utctime,pid,tags:filecount=32,filesize=64m
# due to internationalization enhancements in JDK 9 Elasticsearch need to set the provider to COMPAT otherwise
# time/date parsing will break in an incompatible way for some date patterns and locals
9-:-Djava.locale.providers=COMPAT

# temporary workaround for C2 bug with JDK 10 on hardware with AVX-512
10-:-XX:UseAVX=2
```

Comment: systemctl cat elasticsearch && cat /etc/elasticsearch/jvm.options

Comment: The line for pid 20280 in your `systemctl status` output includes `/bin/java -Xms256m -Xmx256m`, so it appears to be incorporating the values from your `jvm.options`, which suggests the problem lies in a less-obvious place.